# Configure same picklist as single/multiselect on different VF pages

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to SF technology.Here in my requirement I have one object Advertisement__c, it has a picklist named `Locality__c`. This pick list is used on two custom VF pages, on one page I want to use it as single select where as on page I need to use it as multiselect and I have bound this picklist using `<apex:inputfield>` . Please let me know whether is it possible to customize picklist in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in native way. but three are multiple workarounds like: create this picklist as multiselect picklist.

1. Now in one place display it using `apex:inputfield`. and another place get all value using `describe` and then create `selectoption` list and populate this field using single select.

Sample code to get picklist value modify this as per your requirement

```
public List<SelectOption> getCountries()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
    OfficeLocation__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Only the controller will not make the picklist as multiselect. Include VF code as well.